# A problem about equicontinuity.

Tags: real-analysis

Please, help-me to solve this problem:

"let $F=\{f_1,...,f_n,...\}$ be a set of functions $f_n:[-1,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ defined as $f_n(x)=x^{2n}$. Prove that $F$ is not equicontinuous".

If $F$ were equicontinuous at an arbitrary point $x_0$, then given $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $x \in [-1,1], |x-x_0| \Rightarrow |(fx)-f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$, for all $f \in F$.

Then I must prove that there exists $\varepsilon >0$ such that, for all $\delta>0$, it is possible to find $x \in [-1,1]$ such that we have $|x-x_0|< \delta|, but |f(x)-f(x_0)|\ge \varepsilon$, for all $f \in F$.

I can't go any further than this.

Comment: You haven't expressed the negation of equicontinuity correctly.  Once you do that, you'll probably see how to prove it.

Comment: There are only two points where the family is not equicontinuous.

Comment: Hi, Jack! So, what should be the correct negation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the sequence *were* equi-continuous, then there would be a *uniformly* convergent subsequence (by the theorem of Arzela-Ascoli). But the limit of this subsequence would then be continuous (as a uniform limit of continuous functions). But the limit of this subsequence is also the function $f$ such that  $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in (-1,1)$ and $f(-1) = f(1) = 1$. This function is not continuous.